# Retrieve only certain columns eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In short. I've been looking for some way to not retrieve some columns every time I query a model in laravel. Is it possible? For example having something like:

```
Class User extends Model{
   ...
   protected $columns = ["name", "email"];
   ...
```

And every time a query `User` like `User::get()` It only returns the name and email

Comment: Your laravel version?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [hidden](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json).

`protected $hidden = ["values", "i", "want", "to", "hide"];`

Comment: I guess this is the only option. Thanks!

Comment: In case those values are not wanted ever, it could be solution. But I am afraid some of those values could be needed sometimes.

Comment: @Tpojka see my answer. when need to select other columns

Comment: Also when use $hidden it is only hide that columns in attributes. See differebce `$item->getAttributes()` and `$item->toArray()`

Comment: @Davit would prefer you not try to get OP's attention by commenting on my answer. If you could comment on the original question or your own answer would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the columns specifically instead of using **User::get()**

```
    $models = User::select('name', 'email')->get();
```

Comment: That would imply changing a bunch of code inside the page :c

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz ok

Comment: I guess as a side note then... If sometime in the future you need the hidden columns there is a  **withHidden(array|string $attributes)** method on the Model Class

Answer (score 0):

you can filter your columns in two ways

**Method 1**
use `protected $hidden=[]` on your model and list your variables which you prefer to be hidden. 

and also this method will hide your variable permanently and if you want to access your variable again, you have to call it directly,e.g:

```
$user=User::find(1);
$user->your_hidden_variable
```

check [Eloquent Serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization) for more information.

**method 2**
pass an array on getting/selecting

```
$user=User::select(["name","email"])->where("your","condition");
```

OR

```
$user=User::where("your","condition")->get(["your","fields"]);
```